# ErrorException: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 9947 bytes in file no laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tendo esse erro no laravel ao tentar buscar dados do meu banco:

> ErrorException: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 9947 bytes in file

**Controller:**

```
    public function show(Request $request)
{
    $animaisAdocao = animalAdocao::where('id_usuario', $request->id)->get();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($animaisAdocao); $i++){
        $animaisAdocao[$i]['sociabilidade'] = unserialize($animaisAdocao[$i]['sociabilidade']);
        $animaisAdocao[$i]['temperamento'] = unserialize($animaisAdocao[$i]['temperamento']);
        $animaisAdocao[$i]['complementos'] = unserialize($animaisAdocao[$i])['complementos'];

    }


    return response()->json($animaisAdocao);
}
```

Minha rota:

```
Route::get('animalAdocao/{id}', 'AnunciaAdocaoController@show');
```

Meus dados no bd:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]